# Using AltGr + Home/PgUp/PgDown etc. for media keys (US International with AltGr Dead Keys)

Tags: shortcut-keys, xmodmap, media-buttons

For a while I have been using the CODE keyboard shortcuts in which you use the `Fn` key combined with Insert/Home/PgUp/Delete/End/PgDn in order to control media functions. I would like to do something similar with my old Model M (no media keys, no Meta key, no fancy things to configure).

My initial idea was to use AltGr for those shortcuts. I quickly realized that the Gnome Keyboard Shortcuts don't like AltGr+Thing, I assume that it is because the combination does not trigger anything in the layout I am using (US International with AltGr Dead Keys).

After some googling I assumed that a solution would be to use Xmodmap and do something like the following:

`$ xmodmap -e "keycode 112 = Prior NoSymbol Prior NoSymbol XF86AudioRaiseVolume"`

But that does nothing. I clearly am doing something wrong (I suppose I have misunderstood some things in the documentation, or not read them well enough). How can I achieve my goal?

---

Some further debugging information, which may be useful:

The output of the `xev` when doing a AltGr + PgUp is the following:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5000001,
    root 0x6cb, subw 0x0, time 16641710, (2129,943), root:(2349,1147),
    state 0x0, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5000001,
    root 0x6cb, subw 0x0, time 16641743, (2129,943), root:(2349,1147),
    state 0x80, keycode 112 (keysym 0xff55, Prior), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I had already done that to check ISO_Level3_Shift (aka AltGr) was being properly detected (and it is). The keycode for the Prior (aka PgUp, number 112) is properly recognized too. I don't know if Xmodmap is misbehaving or if I misconfigured something.

Comment: What's this keycode value?
What does `xev` command say when you press `AltGr+Insert`?

Comment: @PiotrHenrykDabrowski I just added that output to the question